# Fluid simulation (liquid) flows into certain directions / areas of domain. Any solution?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am working on a scene where I must use a fluid simulatin (liquid). I have set the domain, inflow and collision. When I bake the simulation, the liquid only flows into certain directions (in this case positive y axis.) What I am trying to achieve is for the liquid to flow evenly to the positive x axis, and ofcourse to negative z axis when there is a pore.
Thank you very much for taking your precious time in advance.

[image]

Blender file:
[image]